# Calling datasource.close() in my onDestroy function does not stop errors

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception

I am getting the following error:

`06-05 22:30:29.004: E/Database(410): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here`

Now since I saw that error, I added the following code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (datasource != null) {
        datasource.close();
    }

    if (pdatasource != null) {
        pdatasource.close();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

`datasource` and `pdatasource` are both private within the activies' class.

I am just wondering why am I still getting this error in the console even if I have added the code that will explicitly close it if it is null and the activity has been destroyed? It does not cause crashes or anything, but I do not want to have any errors before putting this app on the market.

Comment: Trying moving the `close()` calls to `onPause()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application
>   did not close the cursor or database object that was opened herea

Your code looks clean and correct. I guess that the most likely you have some "forgotten" database variable in your application you forgot to close. Check it out.

**Note:** Also check used `Cursor` variables as well (they also should be closed before application is getting destroyed).